# SQL Server Replace in MongoDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb

I want to do a replace in projection. Like a SQL Server REPLACE. I'm pretty sure we can handle that in code but looking for some shell commands.

Here is what I have

```
db.OrderHistoryHeader.aggregate([  
   {
      $project:{
        "_id":0,
        "OrderNo":1 // I want to do Replace(OrderNo,'XYZ','ABC')
      }
   }
],
{
allowDiskUse:true
}).pretty();
```

Comment: @micki  we can pass the value of "OrderNo" to a stored javascript function and get back the value right?

Comment: @Veeram please look into above comment

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? You can just do everything in code instead.

Comment: @Krishna I bet you're thinking too much in SQL way. In MongoDB Aggregation Framework is the right tool to perform such data transformations and there's no need to store JS code on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in operator for that currently but you can use [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/#exp._S_indexOfBytes) combined with [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html).

```
db.OrderHistoryHeader.aggregate([
     {
       $addFields:
          {
            index: { $indexOfBytes: [ "$OrderNo", "XYZ" ] },
          }
      },
      {
        $project: {
            OrderNo: {
                $concat: [ 
                    { $substr: [ "$OrderNo", 0, "$index" ] },
                    "ABC",
                    { $substr: [ "$OrderNo", { $add: [3, "$index"] }, -1 ] }
                ]
            }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
            index: 0
        }
      }
   ])
```

Where `3` is the length of text being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replaceOne method
db.collection.replaceOne(filter, replacement, options)

From documentation:
Behavior
replaceOne() replaces the first matching document in the collection that matches the filter, using the replacement document.

upsert
If upsert: true and no documents match the filter, db.collection.replaceOne() creates a new document based on the replacement document.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).